# Synchronization of several enterprise Java application

Tags: java, web-applications, synchronization

My Java Spring application available through load balancing from two Tomcat instances.

Users can send complicated tasks to application which can't be run in parallel and some of them must be skipped if similar task already executed a few hours ago.

I have Oracle DB and RabbitMQ as storages but have no idea how they can be used to perform atomic operations and synchronization between running applications and within threads in selected application.

One of the complication - fail safety, so if one application acquire lock to perform some operation and then halted (or server go down, hardware failure, etc) then lock must been freed after timeout so another application or restored first  application can perform cleanup action and re-run task.

So I look for any possibility to synchronize Java applications in safe way in order to execute task by only one application at time.

**PS** Formally I want persistent storage of:

```
ID
DATE
STATE
```

where `ID` is task type, `DATE` is latest time of changing `STATE` with atomic operations:

- Atomically changing `STATE` from *completed* or *failed* to *executing* with locking on `ID`. If selected `ID` in *executing* or *recovering* `STATE` - return *false*. Otherwise set `STATE` to *executing* and update `DATE` to current time.
- Atomically changing `STATE` from *executing* or *recovering* `STATE` to *recovering* state with updating `DATE` to current if `DATE` too far from current (as mark that task execution or recovering fail). Return *false* if can't acquire lock on `ID` or task is not in *executing* or *recovering* `STATE`.
- Atomically changing `STATE` from *recovering* to *failed* with updating `DATE` to current. Return *false* if can't acquire lock on `ID` or task is not in *recovering* `STATE`.

Seems these operations enough for making failsafe task synchronization...

Comment: Schedule tasks using a shared browsable JMS queue ?

Comment: I think that read operation from queue is atomic, but with application fail we forget this task and that it is in incomplete state (cleanup action required). So I need some protocol/API/support from software/custom DB storage+synchronization to handle this situation.

Comment: Yes. Some sort of GC cleanup thread is required (in a similar fashion sessions are cleared from the sessions cache). I do not know about RabbitMQ but with HornetMQ there is a "shared store" (basically a SAN with a file backed queue)